# How does $P(Z_2 > t) = \int _{t_1}^{t_2}P(Z_2 > t~\mid~Z_1 = \tau)~f_{Z_1}(\tau)\,d\tau$?

Tags: probability

What's the name of this probability law

$$P(Z_2 > t) = \int \limits_{t_1}^{t_2}P(Z_2 > t~\mid~Z_1 = \tau)~f_{Z_1}(\tau)~d\tau\,,$$

where $f_{Z_1}(t)$ is the PDF of $Z_1$?

How to derive it?

Comment: Is $Z_1$ supported on $[t_1,t_2]$? Usually the integral ranges from $-\infty$ to $\infty$

Comment: It's continuous example of full probability. I.e. $\mathbb{P}(Z_2 > t, Z_1 = \tau) = \mathbb{P}(Z_2 > t | Z_1 = \tau) \cdot \mathbb{P}(Z_1 = \tau)$. Hence if you need to compute $\mathbb{P}(Z_2 > t)$ you need to integrate over support of $Z_1$.

Comment: That would be the law of total probability, continuous version.

Comment: openspace makes sense.. one thing That confuses me... I would think $P(Z_1 = \tau) = 0$ if $\tau$ is a continuous variable since $\tau$ is a scalar with an infinitely small width.... but there it is in the conditional probability...

Comment: maybe its ok... because its integrating over a range...

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of conditional expectation of random variables?

Answer (score 0):

This one is kind of weird because they are using a joint probability distribution between a complementary CDF and PDF.  So I invented a new syntax for it, just treat it like its PDF except put a "greater-than sign" in front of the variable to indicate its a complementary CDF.

$$\Pr(Z_1 > t)= f_{Z_1}(>t) = \int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{Z_2Z_1}(>t,~\tau)~d\tau$$

using Bayes law:

$$f_{Z_1}(>t) = \int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{Z_2|Z_1}(>t~\mid~\tau)~f_{Z_1}(\tau)~d\tau$$